# How is lstrip() method removing chars from left?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, strip

My understanding is that the `lstrip(arg)` removes characters from the left based on the value of `arg`.

I am executing the following code:

```
'htp://www.abc.com'.lstrip('/')
```

Output:

```
'htp://www.abc.com'
```

My understanding is that all the characters should be stripped from left until `/` is reached.
In other words, the output should be:

```
'www.abc.com'
```

I am also not sure why running the following code is generating below output:

```
'htp://www.abc.com'.lstrip('/:pth')
```

Output:

```
'www.abc.com'
```

Comment: lstip() strips all the specified characters from the left. try with `//////htp://www.abc.com` see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the `help` function shows the following:

```py
Help on built-in function lstrip:

lstrip(chars=None, /) method of builtins.str instance
    Return a copy of the string with leading whitespace removed.
    
    If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
```

Which, clearly means that any white-space in the starting (i.e. left) will be chopped-off or if the `chars` argument is specified it will remove those characters if and only if the string begins with any of the specified characters i.e. if you pass `'abc'` as an argument then the string should start with any of `'a'`,`'b'` or `'c'` else the function won't change anything.
The string need not begin with the `'abc'` as a whole.

```py
print(' the left strip'.lstrip())    # strips off the whitespace
the left strip
>>> print('ththe left strip'.lstrip('th'))    # strips off the given characters as the string starts with those
e left strip
>>> print('ththe left strip'.lstrip('left'))    # removes 't' as 'left' contatins 't' in it
hthe left strip
>>> print('ththe left strip'.lstrip('zeb'))    # doesn't change anything as the argument passed doesn't match the beggining of the string
ththe left strip
>>> print('ththe left strip'.lstrip('h'))    # doesn't change anything as the argument passed doesn't match the beggining of the string
ththe left strip
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all chars right of a given string try split

```
url = 'htp://www.abc.com'
print(url.split('//')[1])
```

output

```
www.abc.com
```

lstrip only returns a copy of the string with leading characters stripped, not in between

Comment: can you please help me understand output of `'htp://www.abc.com'.lstrip('/:pth')`? I have just now updated my question

Comment: @meallhour `strip()`  treats `'/:pth'` as a *set* of characters to be stripped, not a *prefix* to be removed. So the order of the characters has no visible effect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this :

```
a = 'htp://www.abc.com'
a = a[a.find('/')+1:]
```

From Python Docs :
str.lstrip([chars])

```
Return a copy of the string with leading characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace. **The chars argument is not a prefix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:**
```

Read the last line your doubt will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip), `str.lstrip` can only remove the leading characters specified in its args, or whitespaces if no characters is provided.

You can try using `str.rfind` like this:

```py
>>> url = "https://www.google.com"
>>> url[url.rfind('/')+1:]
'www.google.com'
```